# XML Parsing two loops within same XML

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing, tbxml

I have an XML in this format:

```
<tag>
  <subtag>
     <tag1>..</tag 1>
     <tag2>..</tag 2>
  </subtag>

  <different subtag>
    <tag 3>..</tag 3>
    <tag 4>..</tag 4>
    <tag 3>..</tag 4>
    <tag 4>..</tag 3>
    ......
    .....
    <tag 3>..</tag 3>
    <tag 4>..</tag 4>
  </different subtag>
</tag>
```

Please help in parsing through two tags simultaneously. I am using TBXML parser.Thanks!

Current code:

```
do
    {
        if (element->firstChild)
            [self parsedandSaveXML:element->firstChild];

    if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"subtag"]) { 
      // adding elements to array1
    } 
    if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"different subtag"]) { 
      // adding elements to array2
    } 
}while ((element = element->nextSibling));
```

Comment: i tried to parse like this: if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"subtag"])
        { adding elements to array1}
if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"different subtag"])
        { adding elements to array2}

Comment: added code to question for you

Comment: thanks can u provide some solution also?

Comment: Check this link:http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Traversing_Unknown_elements___attributes.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this is not helpful as the tags are not unknown. I only want to know how to parse two nodes simultaneously.